# NodeJS creating JWT no third party libraries

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, authorization, jwt

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do JWT auth in nodejs using no third party libraries. I'm making my own express for fun to learn as much about node as I can and I want to do it all bare bones nodejs.

Here is what I have so far (basic server), if you could show me how to create a JWT and how to read a JWT and any other cool things about JWTS that you think might help me along my learning path, I would love you forever.

```
(function(){
    var http = require("http");
    const PORT = process.env.PORT;
    const HOST = process.env.IP;

    function requester(req,res){
        if(req.url == "/createBatManJWT"){
            //create JWT
            res.end("Yay I created a JWT");
        }
        if(req.url == "/readBatManJWT"){
            //read JWT
            res.end("yay I read a JWT");
        }
    }    

    var server = http.createServer(requester);

    server.listen(PORT, HOST, function(){
        console.log("Server On");
    });
})();
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of work involved with creating and verifying JWTs, aka [rfc7519](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519.txt), so I would not recommend trying to create your own code unless you have a lot of time to put into testing it.  I like [nJwt](https://github.com/jwtk/njwt) - but I wrote it, so I'm biased :)